# How outer class is able to access the inner member class directly

Tags: java, inner-classes

When we define inner classes, I understand that `static` inner classes are accessed with the outer class and inner member class exist with the instance of the outer class.

The confusion is, if I want to hold an instance of an `non-private` inner member class, then the variable declaration goes like:

```
OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
```

How outer class is able to reference the inner member class like this? What is happening here?

---

Sample Code:

```
public class NestedClasses {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A.B b = new A().new B();   // <- How A is directly accessing B, B is not defined as static.
    A.StaticClass staticClass = new A.StaticClass();
  }
}

class A {
  static int x;
  int y;

  A() {
    System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
  }
  static class StaticClass {
    StaticClass() {
      System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
  class B {
    B() {
      System.out.println(this.getClass().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the simple type name `OuterClass.InnerClass`? That's just the simple naming syntax.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.5.2

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling the constructor using an object instance? `new A().new B();`

Comment: @AJC because we cannot directly instantiate inner member classes without the enclosing object. The instance of an inner member class can exist only when you have an instance of outer class.